# Incorrect display for Objective-C/iPhone 'Hello World' app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am running the 'hello world' app from: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/

I am seriously at like step 2, but I can't figure out this strange little thing, and I don't want to move on until i do. I'm a bit stumped, and I've been poking around all over.

I created a view controller with a single label. It looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of view controller]!

Nice and centered, right?

Well, when I run the ios simulator I get this:

[image: ios simulator]!

I can't figure out why it's off to the right like that. I checked to see if for some reason it was running as iPad app so the X and Y domain were off, but it appears that it is running as iPhone 4s, or at least as much as I can tell. How to get this centered?

I am running Xcode 6 beta version. I have a friend who did this without a similar issue, so I don't think it's a bug in the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add constraints to tell that label where to be. Research AutoLayout constraints: [Autolayout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Currently, that label is positioned exactly where you told it to be. Since you're in the `Any : Any` size class, the origin of that label is something like say `x: 310, y: 300`. The iPhone simulator you're running on has a screen area of `width: 320 height: 420`, so if your label has a width of 20, half of it would be off the screen.

If you had set constraints for the view, autolayout would have dynamically adjusted the origin of your label for you.

Comment: I deleted the whole project and started over. I am getting the exact same problem, so i am pretty stumped. I tried adjusting the view controller category:
![view controller](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/Q5r2QN6T1_nsb1uhXoDkoC1F6xF6iCPXxhaEcba0rqI=w253-h352-no).

Still when i run this in ios simulator I get the label off the right of the screen. 

Any other info/suggestions are GREATLY appreciated. thanks!

Comment: @PeterAndrus, the link you posted is a tutorial that walks you through a project using xcode 5. xcode 6 introduces size classes, which makes a huge difference in regards to placement of views in the storyboard. If you want it to "just work" without using constraints (I don't recommend it, however), you can change the size class by clicking where it says "wAny hAny" and changing your size class to "wCompact hCompact". Seriously though, learn constraints, not workarounds.

Comment: that makes more sense. When you referenced constraints before, i figured they must have been the same in XCode 5 as 6. I thought "they couldn't have changed THAT much, right?". 
However, this makes me realize i shouldn't have ASSumed that. I will give constraints a deeper look and see if I am able to get it right. 

...it still bugs me, though, that my friend was able to get it working without any issues.... on XCode 6....

Comment: Your friend might not have had size classes enabled. Autolayout constraints existed in xcode 5, but size classes didn't. So, if you were using a storyboard for iPhone and dropped a label in the middle it would stay in the middle(ish.. y still would be off depending on screen size). You have size classes enabled (which is good!), so you're designing for ANY size screen. This makes constraints required to make layouts that flow from iPad to iPhone 5s to iPhone 4 to whatever.

Comment: The answer ended up being far simpler: I needed to go to the storyboard, then open the file inspector (View->Utilities->Show File Inspector) and then unclick 'Use Auto Layout'.  
I should have listened to Andrew the first time and read deeper into this link. Thanks for your patience Andrew!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to zoom out the simulator. You can do this by pressing `"command + 3"` while the simulator is running.

Or, you could also do it like this: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Andrew, what you say makes sense, but this is a simple 'Hello World' app, and there is nothing mentioned yet about working with constraints. It just says to drag and drop. Maybe this is something new in XCode 6 where the default settings for constraints are different?

Heisenberg, I tried your suggestion, but got the same thing...WEIRD
![100 percent view](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UPCguUvahuw/VADbLZcbziI/AAAAAAAAF6Y/Nyi5HLfhDxk/w425-h603-no/Screen%2BShot%2B2014-08-29%2Bat%2B12.56.45%2BPM.png)!

I will look into the constraints again....